# How can I retroactively add an e-mail to a thread in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

Let's say I have a large e-mail thread. This e-mail thread is mostly ok, but a key e-mail is missing from the thread because someone didn't reply appropriately at one point. Is there an easy way for me to add this missing e-mail to the thread when I reply, maintaining the appropriate indentation appearance? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in principle you can. In practice however, don't try it. For this to work, you would need to edit the corresponding .msf file. This is an index to the emails, which themselves are all stored in a single file with no structure. The index keeps track of which mails have been viewed, which are replies to other mails, etc. Your thread structure is contained in it. However, the .msf file (mail folder summary) has the [Mork database format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_%28file_format%29), which is very, very hard to parse, let alone edit, for humans.